# Why does the JAVA_HOME set in the Jenkins pipeline say invalid?

Tags: jenkins, environment

I set JDK installations in the Tools section of Jenkins management and named it 'jdk17'.
And the pipeline was written as follows.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        jdk 'jdk17'
    }
    environment {
        JAVA_HOME = "${tool 'jdk17'}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('git clone') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'backend/taskmaster/deploy', credentialsId: 'HJ', url: 'https://lab.ssafy.com/s10-webmobile2-sub2/S10P12A305.git'
            }
        }
        stage('create bootjar'){
            steps{
                echo "JAVA_HOME=${env.JAVA_HOME}"
                sh '''
                    cd taskmaster
                    chmod +x gradlew
                    ./gradlew clean bootJar
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the following error occurred during the ./gradlew execution step.

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk17/abc

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

JAVA_HOME is well established in the folder where jdk17 was installed, but I don't know why it says it's an invalid location.
I want to solve it.

Comment: why there is 'abc' in the end of JAVA_HOME in error message?

Comment: When setting up JDK installations, the Subdirectory name was set to 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and happened to come across this question. For me, the problem was that the string I was assigning to JAVA_HOME wound up having a trailing newline. Once I used strip() on the string, the problem went away. This could be your issue as well, hopefully that helps!